# Adding LD_PRELOAD to 'run' executable in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

When I compile my test application in CLion with gcc 6.2, it outputs

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found
```

Which is obvious, since I am using gcc 4.8 as system compiler, and gcc 6.2 resides in my home folder, and compiled program is using my system libs.

Obvious solution here is to use `LD_PRELOAD`, which is working fine, when I am running my compiled app via console.

**The question**: What shall I put into CMakeList.txt in CLion, so, when I click "Run" in CLion - my compiled app executes as "LD_PRELOAD=something ./myApp" instead of just "./myApp"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979148/clion-cant-find-shared-library-when-running-an-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, helped myself. Added environment variable in build configuration for project in CLion.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile my test application in CLion with gcc 6.2, it outputs

I guess you mean "when I run my test application". That happens because your app was linked to newer version of libstdc++ but can only find older one at startup.

> What shall I put into CMakeList.txt in CLion, so, when I click "Run" in CLion -
>   my compiled app executes as "LD_PRELOAD=something ./myApp" instead of
>   just "./myApp"

You either need to run your app with modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH (so that it points to 6.2's libstdc++, not 4.8's) or build with custom rpath:

```
 gcc -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/new/libstdc++ ...
```