# CLion can't find shared library when running an executable

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am working on a project. I've been using a simple editor so far and my own Makefile to build it. I would like to switch to CLion, though.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918459/using-local-makefile-for-clion-instead-of-cmake) you can tell CMake to run your Makefile. So my `CMake.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(rekotrans_testbed_simulator)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_custom_target(rekotrans_testbed_simulator COMMAND make -C ${rekotrans_testbed_simulator_SOURCE_DIR} CLION_EXE_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

It builds fine. I also set the working directory and pointed at the correct executable.

In my project I test using `cppunit 1.13`. However it can't find the shared library:

```
/home/kunterbunt/dev/comnets/git-repository/rekotrans-testbed-simulator/rekotrans-testbed-simulator-tests: error while loading shared libraries: libcppunit-1.13.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

/usr/local/lib
```

and `/usr/local/lib` contains the library:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/

libcppunit-1.13.so.0@  libcppunit-1.13.so.0.0.2*  libcppunit.a  libcppunit.la*  libcppunit.so@  pkgconfig/
```

`ldd` shows this:

```
ldd /home/kunterbunt/dev/comnets/git-repository/rekotrans-testbed-simulator/rekotrans-testbed-simulator-tests

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc257e8000)
libboost_thread.so.1.63.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f1c73254000)
libboost_system.so.1.63.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f1c73050000)
libboost_date_time.so.1.63.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f1c72e3f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1c72c22000)
libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f1c729a4000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1c727a0000)
libcppunit-1.13.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libcppunit-1.13.so.0 (0x00007f1c72563000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1c721db000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1c71ed7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1c71cc0000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1c71922000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1c7171a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1c7347c000)
```

So why can't CLion find it? Everything works if I run the binary from console.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ldd <your_executable>`?

Comment: Edited to show ldd output.

Comment: My guess is that LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set for CLion as a program. What does `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the terminal *within* CLion?

Comment: Also prints `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: @kunterbunt What if you open CLion from a terminal?

Comment: Huh yeah, that also works. So from the GUI it opens as another user that doesn't have the variable set?

Comment: Apparently... If it's convenient for you, you can edit your `.profile` to set the variable every time you log into a graphical session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [oLen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4184884/olen) correctly pointed out, CLion doesn't seem to start as my user when launched via the GUI (Gnome in my case). I don't know as what it starts, but setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` in `/etc/profile` and rebooting (or resourcing) it makes it work - in a nutshell the variable wasn't set for whatever user is running CLion.

Another way is `Run -> Edit Configurations -> (select your application) -> Environment variables`. Here you can manually set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to whatever you need, in my case to `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux):

If you add your custom library path to the LD configuration, then CLion will find your libraries automatically and you don't have to add them to the run configurations.

On Ubuntu/Debian, you can configure LD by creating a new `.conf` file

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myLocalLibs.conf
```

that simply contains the path to your libraries: `/usr/local/lib`. Finally, call

```
sudo ldconfig
```

to update the LD configuration.

Note that on some systems (Ubuntu/Debian) you cannot set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile or /etc/environment:

> Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in
>   $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use
>   /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files. See [Launchpad bug #366728](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728)
>   for more information.
>   ([help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables))

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer you can go to `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Templates`, choose `CMake Application` (and/or `Google Test`) and set `Environment variables:` to:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-latest/lib64
```

Any new application created from now on will inherit these settings.